# Can't use external monitor's full resolution on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, display, resolution

I just got a brand-new large (34") curved HP monitor.  It works fine on my personal Dell laptop (from mid 2020).  Meaning, it can use its full native resolution of 3440 x 1440.  I also have a Dell work laptop (from mid 2019).  It only allows me to go up to 2560 x something.  On Windows, that's simply the highest res. in the pulldown menu.  I installed HP specific driver and monitor software, no help.  The work Dell powers a very similar Dell external monitor all the way to 3440 x 1440.  So that means the video adapter can handle this.

What to do?  This is a very frustrating problem.  I'm pretty good w/ computers, but I don't even have any "tools" to try to fix this.  Both machines are very up to date in terms of windows, video adapter software, Dell updates, etc.

I connect the monitor to both laptops with the same HDMI cable.

Comment: Such large monitors r!require HDMI 2.0 for the full resolution. Cable and graphic card have to support this. If you have a Displayport try it, 4k support is available in Displayport for a much longer time than in HDMI thus you have a higher chance that it is supported in your 2019 model.

Comment: @Robert you're a genius!!  Yes, I *think* this is the issue!  I tried my work laptop w/ a usb-c cable, and it works at full res!  Thank you so much!  I really wish these things would be easier to figure out.  Like, why can't they more explicitly label the port as "HDMI 1.X"?  And in a font you don't need a magnifying glass for.  Even finding the model num. on a monitor is a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Just copying Robert's comment here:  Such large monitors require HDMI 2.0 for the full resolution. Cable and graphic card have to support this. If you have a Displayport try it, 4k support is available in Displayport for a much longer time than in HDMI thus you have a higher chance that it is supported in your 2019 model.